# Ada: plotting 2d graphs

Tags: graph, ada

it would be interesting to be able to plot a 2D graph within an Ada code rather than having to save values say to file and use an external drawing software afterwards. A search on the web has taken me to two packages: Win_IO and JEWL. I have been able to use WIN_IO though but the documentation is quite poor and having just started using it, it seems that it is not possible to resize the size of the canvas. I use the GPS editor and I get complaint when running Win_IO that some fonts are not available on my system and that the output will be ugly. Finally the plot doesn't itself pop up on the screen; One has to click on the exe file of the file being compiled and linked so as to get the graph.

I have taken a look also at JEWL but it doesn't seem to be able to plot graphs.

Are there more Ada packages available out there for plotting 2D graphs.

Thanks a lot...

---

My experience with GNAVI:

The installation instructions are at

http://www.gnavi.org/index.php?Command=Class&ClassID=Start&CID=381

Basically the installation consists of:
To use:

1. Place this directory on your path
2. cd to gnatcom and run: make install
3. cd to gwindows and run: make UNICODE=1 all
4. run: gnavi_ide and enjoy :-)

But the installation is plagued with errors:

C:\gnavi\gnatcom>install
Installing GNATCOM.....
MAKE Version 5.2  Copyright (c) 1987, 2000 Borland
Error makefile 2: Command syntax error
*** 1 errors during make ***
Install Completed

C:\gnavi\gwindows>make UNICODE=1 all
MAKE Version 5.2  Copyright (c) 1987, 2000 Borland
Error makefile 2: Command syntax error
*** 1 errors during make ***

And though C:GNAVI is on my path, the IDE still complains that icg.exe which is found in C:GNAVI is not on the path.`This is trouble with software which has not been fully tested!!! I was very disappointed that people can write irresponsible and incomplete installation instructions. Have the developers even found out that whether a normal user can install their software?

I have also try to look at AdaDesigner at https://gna.org/projects/adadesigner

Here, FireFox complains: This Connection is Untrusted

gna.org uses an invalid security certificate.

The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate is unknown.

I decided not to visit such a website.

Comment: I don't use GNAVI myself. However, I do subscribe to one of its mailing lists (gnavi-discuss@lists.sourceforge.net). A rather high percentage of the messages are about installation issues. The good news is that means you might be able to figure out the problem by looking through its archive: http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=gnavi-discuss

Comment: As for the security certificate issue, I got that with IE as well. Since we have professionally maintained virus checkers and whatnot here, I went ahead and clicked through. Didn't seem to hurt my system any. I understand not wanting to take chances on your own machine though.

Comment: Errr...one thing I might ask, where are you getting your `make.exe` from? That looks like a Borland make, rather than the one that comes with Gnat. A non-gnu make is likely to be quite different (particularly where things like file paths are concerned). If that's the issue, you need reorder the directories in your `PATH` so gnat's make is found first.

Comment: Try http://gna.org/projects/adadesigner

Comment: Thanks for all your comments and for the new link to AdaDesigner. I read its documentation but it doesn't seem to be a program for creating 2D graphs.

Comment: T.E.D: These days it's better to stay out of sites that can possibly cause problems. I believe that if the developers were active, they should have noticed this problem and corrected it.

Comment: Yes, the make.exe comes from the GNAVI package itself. I looked in my GNAT directory and saw a gnatmake.exe file. Did u mean that I use this file instead? I can try maybe to delete the make in GNAVI and copy the GNAT's gntamake.exe file in the GNAVI directory.

Comment: Yes, I have been on the sourceforge.net site for GNAVI and as you mentioned, it seems that many have installation issues. But I have not been able to identify a post which discusses similar issues that I have. I'll try PLPlot first as trashgod suggests. Perhaps this will work better.

Comment: It doesn't seem that gnatmake.exe is the file to be used here.

Comment: I created a new post in connection with PLplot installation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218154/ada-and-plplot-installation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PLplot](http://plplot.sourceforge.net/) is a cross-platform package for creating scientific plots. It has a well-documented [Ada binding](http://plplot.sourceforge.net/docbook-manual/plplot-html-5.15.0/ada.html). For reference, this [gallery](http://plplot.sourceforge.net/examples.php) illustrates a variety of plots. Click a thumbnail to view a full-size image. Click either Ada tab (standard or traditional) to see the corresponding source code.

Comment: Thanks. I've taken a look at PLplot. This one seems to be well suited for scientific plotting and the good thing is that it comes with a good manual. I haven't yet installed it but I'll do it.

Comment: I created a new post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218154/ada-and-plplot-installation .

Answer (score 2):

I'd give a try to [GTKAda](http://libre.adacore.com/libre/tools/gtkada/). I'm not completely sure this subsystem would allow you to do 2D graphs as I've never used it for that purpose, but it can be done with GTK+ (C/C++).

There is also a [guide](http://libre.adacore.com/wp-content/files/auto_update/gtkada-docs/gtkada_ug/gtkada_ug.html) on GTKAda and a [reference manual](http://www2.adacore.com/wp-content/files/auto_update/gtkada-docs/gtkada_rm/gtkada_rm/), some documentation on the GTK toolkit itself may also come handy.

Comment: Thanks. For Win_IO (http://www.ctr.unican.es/Win_IO/) to work, GTKAda must be installed. I did that yesterday and could make Win_IO to work. It was easy to add the necessary folders and link to a project file within GTKAda using the GPS editor. However, I'm not satisfied with Win_IO. One can plot only very short sequence of data. I don't know if I have the ability to use GTKAda directly.

Comment: You can certianly draw lines and points with GTK. Kinda like swatting a fly with a sledgehammer, but it will do the job.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my comments down under your answer on what I would really like to do.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on exactly what you want to do. For graphing node-based diagrams, the first thing I'd look into using is [Graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/). It has its own special graphing language it uses, but I'm all about using Domain Specific Languages when appropriate. Ada has great interoperability, so using DSLs with it can really make it powerful.

An example I found is [AdaDesigner](https://web.archive.org/web/20170224191602/http://gna.org/projects/adadesigner), which generates Graphviz DOT files to help visualze the structure of Ada code.

The one time in the past I had to do simple plotting, it was for a web app. I ended up dynamically generating [SVG](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/) pages on the server side (even though it was poorly supported then). Support is better now, so I'd definitely use it again today.

If working directly on a Windows PC display appeals more to you, there are several options for GUI bindings, all of which should support drawing lines and points on a canvas. In addtion to GTK (which is both powerful and portable), there are a few Win32 API's floating around. I think one comes with Gnat. Another you might not be aware of is GWindows. It is part of [GNAVI](https://web.archive.org/web/20181117140701/http://www.gnavi.org:80/), which aims to be sort of an OpenSource alternative to Delphi. It isn't the most active of projects, but is (reportedly) quite useable, and is still being worked on and used. Here are [some screenshots](https://web.archive.org/web/20181117143448/http://www.gnavi.org:80/images/users/imagespy.html) of it being used for plotting.
[image]
<sub>(source: [gnavi.org](http://www.gnavi.org/images/usersmini/imagespygraph.png))</sub>

Comment: Thanks. I had problems with the installation on GNAVI. See bottom information of my post.

Comment: Also problems to reach AdaDesigner

Comment: I would like to be able to plot 2D graphs (Y versus X values) from Ada itself without having recourse to save to files and using an external plotting program like Matlab, gnuplot, etc...

Answer (score 0):

[MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net/) is cross-platform GPL plotting library. It have C interface, so you can use it from yours code too. Also it can create a window with graphics -- i.e. you don't need to study/use other widget libraries in simplest case.