# Ada: cmake and PLplot installation on Windows

Tags: graph, cmake, ada, failed-installation

This is a follow-up of the post at [Ada: plotting 2d graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210207/ada-plotting-2d-graphs) . I decided to create a new post as this is a separate issue. The installation of PLplot for Windows is at: http://www.miscdebris.net/plplot_wiki/index.php?title=Specifics_for_various_platforms#Windows . The installation is as follows:

```
cd plplot
mkdir buildmingw
cd buildmingw
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install ..
mingw32-make
mingw32-make install
```

I decided to go for the MinGW instillation by downloading the exe file from http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/ . I also got cmake for Windows here: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html .

Now, on running the fourth instruction for installing PLplot (see above), I get:

```
C:\plplot-5.9.6\buildmingw>cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=ins
tall ..
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermine
CCompiler.cmake:44 (MESSAGE):
Could not find compiler set in environment variable CC:

cl.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:38 (project)


CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be
built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be
built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:C:/plplot-5.9.6/buildmingw/CMakeFi
les/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

C:\plplot-5.9.6\buildmingw>
```

I chose in the installation options to let cmake create the necessary system paths. I wonder why the environment variables CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ENV_VAR and CMAKE_C_COMPILER were not created during the installation. Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot..

Comment: The first place I'd look for help on this is the docs (and any support lists) for your Ada bindings to plplot. It could be that they don't expect you to be using CMAKE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with `CMake`, but one of the methods in the FAQ [*How do I use a different compiler?*](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_do_I_use_a_different_compiler.3F) may help. I'm guessing that the pre-built Windows binary can't know what compiler you're using, so it has to rely on the `CC` and `CXX` environment variables.

Comment: Thanks. I have borland C, MVS, GNAT on my path. I will have to read deeper and see why it can't see a compiler and perhaps I'll have to set the variables manually.

Comment: I think that I will stop trying to solve this problem. There is not much information for Windows machines.

Comment: I've decided to raise this question on a more Ada specific forum: comp.lang.ada .