# Create an SVG file with ada

Tags: svg, ada

I would like to learn how to create an SVG image using ada code. 
Any help is appriciated !

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

SVG is coded as an XML file. You need to learn about the SVG format, which is programming language-independent, and then simply write XML files utilizing that format.

Ada programs can write XML files with the aid of [Ada.Text_IO](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-10-1.html), [XMLAda](http://libre.adacore.com/tools/xmlada/), or [XML EZ Out](http://www.mckae.com/xmlEz.html), among others.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [PLplot](http://plplot.sourceforge.net/).

*Lanuage bindings:*

- **Ada**
- C/C++/D
- Fortran 77/90
- Java
- Lisp
- Lua
- OCaml
- Octave
- Perl
- Python
- Tcl/Tk

*Output file formats:*

- CGM
- GIF
- JPEG
- LaTeX
- PBM
- PDF
- PNG
- PostScript
- **SVG**
- Xfig

for documentation see project website.

**see also:** [Ada: plotting 2d graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210207/ada-plotting-2d-graphs/3213050)